# How do you center the label in a Flutter DataColumn widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I can center the DataCell in a DataRow but how do you do it for the DataColumn label?

I want the first DataColumn left justified and the rest centered.  Wrapping the label in a Center widget does not take effect.

```
new DataColumn(
            label: Center(
              child: Text(statName,textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
            )
        );
```

[image: Center Widget is not applied to Text child]

Answer (score 33):

Found how:

```
DataColumn(
    label: Expanded(
        child: Text(
  'Label',
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
))),
```

Comment: after using this i got this error ```Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.

The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type BoxParentData.

Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a Align widget.```

Comment: Which Flutter version? I just tested it again on 2.10.3 and it is working.

Comment: i am also using current latest version

Comment: Hey man, post the code that is giving you an error as another question, so I can try to help you. I believe it is not related to the snippet above.

Comment: Expanded cannot be used inside DataColumn if you have a Stack widget in the parent tree, You get the error that "Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.  The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type BoxParentData.  Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets. The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a Align widget."
test-
flutter run -d chrome --release

Comment: I used SizedBox with a fixed width and a Center widget that carriers the Text widget aligned in Center

Comment: As of December 1, 2022, with Flutter 3.3.8 stable, this will get rid of the overflow right issue when text is too long. I used this, then set softWrap to true since long text was being cut off.

Comment: I had an `Expanded` in the DataCell as well as the DataColumn and that was causing the error mentioned above @Adnanhaider Removing it from DataCell was enough. And then in DataColumn I have ~ Expanded(...ConstrainedBox...Column(mainAxis: centerAlign ... Text))))

Answer (score 7):

For this question I also accept **Rodrigo Boratto**'s answer. Tested on flutter v3.7.3

I came here to get an answer for "How to center a DataCell". I put my finding here for anyone interested.

```
DataCell(
  Align(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    child: Text(
        match['score'],
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to wrap the contents of the Label in a `Center` widget.  There's also an Align widget that uses `alignment: Alignment.center` and your Text as it's child.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Unfortunately, even with the label: contents (Text) wrapped with either Align or Center does not move it from its left aligned position.  Tried to Center label contents and Align as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is how i resolved this issue :

```
DataColumn(
            label: Center(
            widthFactor: 5.0, // You can set as per your requirement.
            child: Text(
            'View',
            style: style_16_bold_primary,
            ),
          ),
      ),
```

Comment: The question is already saying that `Center` didn't work for him.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and solved the issue by commenting the following code section in data_table.dart file.

```
if (onSort != null) {
  final Widget arrow = _SortArrow(
    visible: sorted,
    down: sorted ? ascending : null,
    duration: _sortArrowAnimationDuration,
  );
  const Widget arrowPadding = SizedBox(width: _sortArrowPadding);
  label = Row(
    textDirection: numeric ? TextDirection.rtl : null,
    children: <Widget>[ label, arrowPadding, arrow ],
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't think the changing core functions are a good idea. Maybe extend from them and change the methods you want would be more appropriate.