# Flutter DataTable DataColumns Text Does Not Center

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to center my data column names but flutter datable is automatically setting all text to the left due to the numeric boolean (Whether this column represents numeric data or not. The contents of cells of columns containing numeric data are right-aligned.) Is there a way I can override it so my column names are centerred?

```dart
newDataColumn(String data) {
    if (data == null)
      return null;
    else
      return (DataColumn(
        label: Expanded(
          child: Text(
            data.replaceAll(' ', '\n'),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            maxLines: 2,
          ),
        ),
        onSort: (i, b) {
          setState(
            () {
              if (sorted % 2 == 0) {
                vendors.sort((a, b) =>
                    a.returnValue(data).compareTo(b.returnValue(data)));
              } else {
                vendors.sort((a, b) =>
                    b.returnValue(data).compareTo(a.returnValue(data)));
              }
            },
          );
          sorted += 1;
        },
      ));
}
```

[image: How it looks]

Comment: Wrap the `Text` widget with `Center` or `Align`. It should work.

Comment: Tried both ways, does not work.

Comment: Give it a try by removing the `Expanded` widget.

Comment: No difference. Ive tried using center, align, expanded, nothing seems to work. I've been stuck on this for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked before: [How do you center the label in a Flutter DataColumn widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56615116/how-do-you-center-the-label-in-a-flutter-datacolumn-widget) and I would advise to use the suggested method here.

Comment: I've seen this exact post before but for some reason it doesn't work for me.